# Vue.js, множество вложенных компонентов и $refs - как с этим работать?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Имеется такая иерархия компонентов:

```
-| Post
----| CommentBlock
-------| Comments
```

Внутри компонента Comments имеется `v-for`, для каждого элемента которого прописан `ref`.

Если обратиться к списку (`this.$refs`) локально, то есть внутри компонента Comments, то все успешно. Я вижу все `$refs`.

Но как получить этот список в компоненте Post? Я хочу прямо внутри Post, зная `ref` комментария, получить этот комментарий.

*P. S. Само содержимое поста и комментарии подкружаются с помощью API.*

Comment: Боюсь, придется все-таки описать, зачем вам нужно получать этот комментарий внутри родителя

Comment: @etki отображение комментария внутри поста. Луче не спрашивайте зачем это нужно и как определяется этот `ref` :) Просто есть такой сценарий в проекте, когда необходимо вывести комментарий.

Comment: Пока что оптимальным сценарием выглядит выделение и выборка этого комментария на уровне данных, и, соответственно, вывод в посте части его внутреннего состояния, а не поиск среди других компонентов. Чисто физически это может быть ссылкой на ровно тот же объект, реактивность которого полностью сохранится.

Comment: @etki еще проблема в том, что нужно найти именно этот комментарий. найти для изменения состояния этого комментария. Все немного сложнее. То есть, формируется список комментариев с указанием `ref` для каждого. Если в посте имеется `ref` комментария, то нужно найти этот комментарий в списке, произвести уже операции (например, это вызов метода, который находится внутри компонента Comment) над ним. Опять же пример - это смена определенного флага. Если было бы просто, то я бы получил этот комментарий по отдельному запросу API.

Comment: @Colibri как вариант, Вы можете воспользоватся глобальной шиной данных https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Коммуникация-между-компонентами-не-связанными-иерархически а не искать нужный комментарий в дереве компонентов. Здесь вы сразу можете построить связь `Post <-> Comment` перепрыгивая через промежуточное звено

Comment: @GONG кстати, неплохой вариант. Нужно будет попробовать. Спасибо за совет :)